# Как можно проинициализировать нулями структуру в си

Tags: c, stm32

Есть у меня вот такая структура:

```
    typedef struct {
    char str[4][256];
    int  sizeStr;
} _StrCalc;
 _StrCalc StrCalc;
```

Структура глобальная нужно проинициализировать ее нулями. Как это можно сделать кроме 'memset()'?

Comment: Если глобальная - она уже проинициализирована нулями...

Comment: нет в микроконтроллерах не инициализируется.

Comment: А, простите, не обратил внимания на метку.

Comment: @zhilenkov, ты что-то недоговариваешь... или у тебя сломанный компилятор, или ты сам ему как-то сказал ничего не инициализировать, или ты смотришь значение до того как инициализирующий код выполнится (до запуска `main()`)... в общем [mcve] с объяснением, как и чем компилируешь в студию...

Comment: В смысли чем. Запустил программу считал память и все. Там все 0xff.

Comment: интересно чем memset не угодил ... А вообще делаете просто `char *x` указывающий на эту структуру и `for(i=0;i < sizeof(_StrCalc); i++) x[i]=0`

Comment: @zhilenkov, что/чем/как скомпилировал? «в микроконтроллерах» обычно всё должно точно также прекрасно инициализироваться нулями — в противном случае это грубое несоответствие стандарту... если, конечно, явно компилятору не сказать «компилировать бинарник без Си'шного рантайма» или что-то подобное... ну а если ты именно этого и хотел, то ССЗБ и непонятно, почему, `memset`'ом не хочешь пользоваться...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы компилируете в IAR, то всё инициализируется автоматически. Если в Keil или других системах, основанных на GCC, то ищите файл `startup_stm32f*.asm`. В нём содержится код, который как раз выполняет инициализацию статической памяти. Вот пример:

```
Reset_Handler:

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */
  movs r1, #0
  b LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr r3, =_sidata
  ldr r3, [r3, r1]
  str r3, [r0, r1]
  adds r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr r0, =_sdata
  ldr r3, =_edata
  adds r2, r0, r1
  cmp r2, r3
  bcc CopyDataInit
  ldr r2, =_sbss
  b LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */
FillZerobss:
  movs r3, #0
  str r3, [r2], #4

LoopFillZerobss:
  ldr r3, = _ebss
  cmp r2, r3
  bcc FillZerobss
```

В коде присутствуют константы `_sbss`, `_sidata`, `_edata` и т.д. Они заданы в скрипте линкера (файл с расширением LD).

Вам нужно:

1. проверить наличие указанного кода;
2. проверить правильность констант в скрипте линкера.